# Schedule a series of 1:1 contests so that each entrant plays against every other

Tags: python, combinatorics

My sister is organizing a Majong tournament. She wants to set up a set of round-robin rounds.

There will be 16 players at 4 tables; 4 players per table. Players will play 5 rounds. She wants every player to play with every other player.

I analyzed this problem and determined that in each round every player would play with three others hence, in 5 rounds it should be possible that they always play with someone different.

I wrote some Python code that worked perfectly however, I think I could have written better code. For instance, can my for loops be done with list comprehensions?

```
# indicates if a player has been seated
#   This is reset before each set of table assignments are made
#   key: player; value: True/False
seated={}

# indicates who has played with who
# key: player; value: list of players
played_with = {}

# indicates who has already played with
# all the players at a table
#  key: table; value: list of players
played_with_table = {}

# seating assignments
#   key: round; value: seating dict
#     seating dict: key: table; value: list of players
rounds = {}

# initialize player dictionaries
for player in range(number_of_players):
    played_with[player] = []
    seated[player] = False

# initialize table dictionaries
for table in range(number_of_tables):
    single_seating[table] = []
    played_with_table[table] = []

# (This was done so dict.extend will work on an empty list)

for _round in range(number_of_rounds):
        
    for player in range(number_of_players):
        for table in range(number_of_tables):
        
            # if there are steats at the table
            if len(single_seating[table]) < 4:
        
                # and if the new player hasn't played with anyone
                if player not in played_with_table[table]:
            
                    # add player to the table
                    single_seating[table].extend([player])
                
                    # add who that player has played with
                    played_with_table[table].extend(played_with[player])
            
                    seated[player] = True
            
                    break # (this seems inelegant)

    # this never happened with 5 rounds, 16 players, at 4 tables
    if not seated[player]:
        print(f"couldn't find a seat for player {player}")

    # capture who has played with who
    for table in single_seating.keys():
        for player in single_seating[table]:
    
            # other_players is everyone at the table except the player
            other_players = [person for person in single_seating[table] if person not in [player]]
            played_with[player].extend(other_players)

    # add the seating arragngement for this round
    rounds[_round] = dict(single_seating)

    # clear single round dictionaries

    for player in range(number_of_players):
        seated[player] = False

    for table in range(number_of_tables):
        single_seating[table] = []
        played_with_table[table] = []
```

The result is in the rounds dictionary. The code works great. I just think I could have done a better job in writing it.

Answer (score 4):

### Algorithm

The problem you are trying to solve is called Social Golfer Problem. It is currently unsolved for the general case. Your algorithm however, is no where close to good. You got lucky that the code output something instead of just printing `Could not find player`. This problem is typically modelled as a SAT formulations (propositional satisfiability problem) or as a Constraint programming problem.

### Code Review

1. You don't need to use `dicts` here. Since your `player` is an int lists can work here.
2. Initialize lists or sets or dicts using comprehension instead of in a for loop
3. Create variables in the smallest scope. Makes it easier to read.
4. Instead of resetting variables like `seated` at every iteration create them in the for loop at the start
5. The loop where you say `break # (this seems inelegant)` can easily be converted into a find statement by using `next` and `generator` expression.
6. Use generator instead of list comprehension for `other_players`
7. Magic number '4'. Name it appropriately in this case `number_of_players_per_table`
8. No need to name variable too verbosely `num_players` is fine.
9. Raise an error if there is. Don't just print and proceed as if nothing happened.
10. `played_with_table` is an extremely bad name as it does not signify with it is doing. A better name would be `incompatible_players`.
11. `played_with_table` must be a `list` of `set`s instead of a dictionary of lists. This will make the complexity of `player not in played_with_table[table]` constant instead of linear.
12. Use `append(element)` instead of `extend([element])` for adding a single element to a list

### Code

Here is the code with all suggestions applied

```
def main():

    num_tables = 4
    num_rounds = 5
    num_players_per_table = 4
    num_players = num_players_per_table * num_tables

    played_with = [[] for _ in range(num_players)]    
    rounds = []

    for _ in range(num_rounds):

        seating = [[] for _ in range(num_tables)]
        incompatible_players = [set() for _ in range(num_tables)]

        for player in range(num_players):
            table = next(
                (
                    table for table in range(num_tables)
                    if len(seating[table]) < num_players_per_table
                        and player not in incompatible_players[table]
                ), None
            )
            
            if table is None:
                raise RuntimeError(f"couldn't find a seat for player {player}")
     
            seating[table].append(player)        
            incompatible_players[table].update(played_with[player])
        
        for table in seating:
            for player in table:
                other_players = (person for person in table if person != player)
                played_with[player].extend(other_players)

        rounds.append(seating)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code Review

The code, at present, is a large wall of code, and using global variables.  This is hard to use, manage and/or test.  There are no type-hints, so it is difficult to tell how the data is being transformed.

(Ajinkya got rid of global variables by moving everything into one function with no input and no output, so I can't say that is an improvement)

### Type Hints

To start with, you should add some type hints.  This will help readers (including future you) understand what values are being passed around.  Additionally, `mypy` can be used to verify that the code produces the values you expect it to.

For example:

```
from typing import Iterable

type Player = int
type Players = Iterable[Player]
type Table = set[Player]
type Round = list[Table]
type Tournament = list[Round]
```

At this point, it is immediately clear that:

- a player will be an integer,
- some kind of collection (set, list, tuple, ...) will be used to describe all the players,
- a table will be represented as a set of players,
- a round is composed of a list of tables, and
- the entire tournament is a list of rounds.

### Tournament

With this, we can mock-up an initial function for creating the tournament:

```
def tournament(players: Players, seats: int) -> Tournament:
    """
    Create a tournament composed of multiple rounds, of tables
    of players, where every player plays every other player
    exactly once.
    """

    if (len(players) - 1) % (seats - 1) != 0:
        raise ValueError("Impossible")

    all_players = set(players)
    available_partners = [all_players - {player} for player in players]

    rounds = []
    while any(available_partners):
        rounds.append(make_round())

    return rounds
```

Here, the `tournament()` function takes in the collection of players and the number of seats at a table, and returns a corresponding `Tournament`.  It has a `"""docstring"""` which gives a brief overview of the function.

The function starts off with a quick check: for a given player occupying a seat at some table, the number of "other" players must be evenly divisible by the number of "other" seats.

Next, for every player, we construct a set of every other player that they must partner up with in the tournament.

The function then constructs a list of rounds, and while `any` of the available partner sets is true-ish (non-empty), we ask some other function to make a round which we then append to the list of rounds, which is finally returned to the caller.

### Helper function

We can now work on some helper functions.  Obviously, we need the `make_round()` function, which returns the constructed `Round`:

```
    def make_round() -> Round:
        """
        Create one round in a round robin tournament
        """

        to_be_seated = set(players)

        the_round = []
        while len(to_be_seated) >= seats:
            table = make_table(to_be_seated)
            the_round.append(table)
            to_be_seated -= table

        return the_round
```

From the collection of players (for the moment, don't worry about where this comes from), we construct a `set`.

While the set of players "to be seated" has can fill the number of seats at a table, we call a function to make a new table, append that to a list of tables in the round, and then remove the players at that table from the set of players left to be seated.

### Helper for the Helper

Now we need a `make_table()` helper function.  It takes a set of players still to be seated, finds 4 that satisfy the criteria, and returns that set as a `Table`:

```
    def make_table(to_be_seated: set[Player]) -> Table:
        """
        Create a table of players which haven't played with
        each other yet, using a simple, greedy approach.

        Side effect: Removes the table's players from the
        `available_partners` of each player at the table.
        """

        available = set(to_be_seated)
        table = set()
        for _ in range(seats):
            player = next(iter(available))
            table.add(player)
            available &= available_partners[player]

        for player in table:
            available_partners[player] -= table

        return table
```

### Non-globals

Both helper functions use `seats`.  The `make_round` function uses `players`, and `make_table` function additionally uses and modifies `available_partners`.  These variables were not passed into the functions are arguments, but we don't want them to be global variables either.

The solution I use here is inner functions.  We package both `make_round` and `make_table` inside the `tournament` function, which adds tournament's local variables to the scope of the inner functions.

### Complete code

```
from typing import Iterable

type Player = int
type Players = Iterable[Player]
type Table = set[Player]
type Round = list[Table]
type Tournament = list[Round]


def tournament(players: Players, seats: int) -> Tournament:
    """
    Create a tournament composed of multiple rounds, of tables
    of players, where every player plays every other player
    exactly once.
    """


    def make_table(to_be_seated: set[Player]) -> Table:
        """
        Create a table of players which haven't played with
        each other yet, using a simple, greedy approach.

        Side effect: Removes the table's players from the
        `available_partners` of each player at the table.
        """

        available = set(to_be_seated)
        table = set()
        for _ in range(seats):
            player = next(iter(available))
            table.add(player)
            available &= available_partners[player]

        for player in table:
            available_partners[player] -= table

        return table


    def make_round() -> Round:
        """
        Create one round in a round robin tournament
        """

        to_be_seated = set(players)

        the_round = []
        while len(to_be_seated) >= seats:
            table = make_table(to_be_seated)
            the_round.append(table)
            to_be_seated -= table

        return the_round


    if (len(players) - 1) % (seats - 1) != 0:
        raise ValueError("Impossible")

    all_players = set(players)
    available_partners = [all_players - {player} for player in players]

    rounds = []
    while any(available_partners):
        rounds.append(make_round())

    return rounds


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tourney = tournament(range(16), 4)
    for rnd in tourney:
        print(rnd)
```

### Output

```
[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11}, {12, 13, 14, 15}]
[{0, 8, 4, 12}, {1, 13, 5, 9}, {2, 10, 6, 14}, {3, 11, 7, 15}]
[{0, 10, 5, 15}, {1, 11, 4, 14}, {8, 2, 13, 7}, {9, 3, 12, 6}]
[{0, 11, 13, 6}, {1, 10, 12, 7}, {9, 2, 4, 15}, {8, 3, 5, 14}]
[{0, 9, 14, 7}, {8, 1, 6, 15}, {2, 11, 12, 5}, {10, 3, 4, 13}]
```

### Future Work

With the code broken up into helper functions, you can more easily add additional features.  For example: limited tables (28 players, 4 seats per table, but only 4 tables, where 12 people must sit out each round), or allow for an empty seats (15 players, 4 seats, 4 tables).

When expanding the functionality, you probably want to test the helper functions, which means you can't embed them inside other functions.  Instead, you'd need to pass in all parameters you're using, or use a class and rely on members like `self._seats` for the additional information.